# OCamlで自分が定義した演算子の結合性は？

Tags: ocaml

タイトルのようにOCamlで自分が定義した演算子の結合性を質問したいと思います。

ためしたこと：

```
let (^-^) a b = a - b;;
3 ^-^ 2 ^-^ 1;;
- : int = 2
```

ここは右結合ですね、

補充：

```
let (||>) a b = a - b;;
3 ||> 2 ||> 1;;
- : int = 0
```

なぜここでは左結合になるでしょう？

どんなルールで結合性が決まるのですか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

定義した演算子の名前がどの記号から始まるかによって、優先度と結合性が変わります。詳しくは OCaml のマニュアルをご覧ください: https://ocaml.org/manual/expr.html#ss%3Aprecedence-and-associativity

今回の場合だと、`(^-^)` は `^` から始まるので右結合、`(||>)` は `|` から始まるので左結合です。

Comment: ありがとう御座います。